# Flex Items Leaving Empty Space on right side of Container while Shrinking

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#wrap {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 72%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 24px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrap2 {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  margin-left:10px;
  width:28%;
  min-height:100%;
}

.le{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 28%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  max-width: 80px;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<div id ="container">
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="le"></div>
  <div class="le"></div>
  <div class="le"></div>
  <div class="le"></div>
  <div class="le"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrap2">
</div>
</div>
```

When we Shrink the Screen we see there is a Empty Space in the wrap div on the right side is there a way to prevent that when we shrink we increase the item size i:e the le item.

I am trying to make sure the empty space doesn't look off to the user as the user shrinks the browser. what are the possible ways to fix this

[image]

Comment: First off, id's are unique. So change each `id="le"` to `class="le"`.

Comment: @psdpainter i changed it but how does it effect the problem statement?

Comment: That's in addition to the problem statement. Have you tried adding the property `justify-content: space-between` to `#wrap`?

Answer (score 2):

That's a prime example of something that CSS Grid will do better than flexbox. Something like this:

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 72%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 24px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrap2 {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  min-height:100%;
}

.le {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id ="container">
  
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="le"></div>
    <div class="le"></div>
    <div class="le"></div>
    <div class="le"></div>
    <div class="le"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="wrap2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we do away this `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));` line in the wrap and have the width 100% also in this running example all are in same line if we have the items moved to next line

Comment: also what does `1fr` signify , can you please explain this solution might be of help

Comment: No, this line is what does the thing. It, and the `fr` unit (which means one fraction of the grid) are part of the [CSS Grid Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). I didn't understand the rest of the question, sorry. If you click on expand snippet, run it and resize you window, you will see the behavior.